# A better way to build a custom SUM function which takes a list of Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, sum, expression, addition

I've defined the following method:

```
public static Expression Sum(IList<Expression> expressions)
{
    Expression result = expressions[0];
    foreach (var expression in expressions.Skip(1))
    {
        result = Expression.Add(result, expression);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
var number1 = Expression.Constant(42.0);
var number2 = Expression.Constant(10.0);

var resultExpression = Sum(new { number1, number2 });
var value = Expression.Lambda(resultExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

However when adding a large number of expressions, I think the performance is not ok.

So I was wondering if a method can be created which used Enumerable.Sum or Queryable.Sum to do the work.

Comment: why not `var value = 42 + 10`? ;P What are your requirements to use expressions? Do you want to add 2 expressions, or a list of expressions or a list of expressions and a list of integers...?

Comment: Why are you using an expression tree to sum two numbers? There are two main uses for expression trees: being used with Entity Framework (or similar) and building dynamic code **that must be reused multiple times**.

Comment: Sorry but what are you trying to do here. The best way to increase performance is to do a single compile.

Comment: I'm trying to build an excel formula parser to parse formulas into linq expression trees. See example here: https://github.com/StefH/ExcelFormulaParser/tree/master/src/ExcelFormulaExpressionParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are redifining the Aggregate method, that uses a previous `Add` expression and current expression of your list of expression. Change your code to this:

```
return expressions.Aggregate((previousExpr, currentExpr) => Expression.Add(previousExpr, currentExpr));
```

I'm not sure this is faster, but is cleaner.
`previousExpr` contains the exression result to sum

Comment: @StefHeyenrath Then the problem is probably that you aren't caching the compiled expression after you generate it.

Comment: @xanatos any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. An even shorter code could be like : return expressions.Aggregate(Expression.Add);